# Updating a node with merge using Py2Neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to merge and then update a graph using the py2neo library. My code looks roughly like

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

graph = Graph(host, auth=(user, password,))

tx = graph.begin()
alice = Node("Person", name="Alice")
bob = Node("Person", name="Bob")
KNOWS = Relationship(alice, "KNOWS", bob)
tx.create(KNOWS)
graph.commit(tx)
```

This creates the nodes and edges as expected as

```
(:Person {name: "Alice"})-[:KNOWS]->(:Person {name: "Bob"})
```

If I try to modify `alice` in a new transaction though, I get no change

e.g.

```py
new_tx = graph.begin()
alice["age"] = 32
new_tx.merge(alice, "Person", "name")
graph.commit(new_tx)
```

I suspect I have misunderstood how the `Transaction` works here. I would expect the above to be equivalent to either finding Alice and updating with the new property or creating a new node.

Update: I have discovered the `Graph.push` method, but would still appreciate advice on best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a primary key to let the `MERGE` know which property to use as a primary key. From the documentation:

> The primary property key used for Cypher MATCH and MERGE operations.
> If undefined, the special value of "**id**" is used to hinge
> uniqueness on the internal node ID instead of a property. Note that
> this alters the behaviour of operations such as Graph.create() and
> Graph.merge() on GraphObject instances.

It's probably best practice to define a custom class for every node type and define the primary key there.

```
class Person(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "name"

    name = Property()
    born = Property()

    acted_in = RelatedTo(Movie)
    directed = RelatedTo(Movie)
    produced = RelatedTo(Movie)
```